# Request entity too large when upload file using Nodejs api on AWS s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, express, amazon-s3

I find many solution on stackoverflow but still getting error In some device When i upload more than 2 image on multipart in node.js api then getting this error
"`Request entity too large`"

I use `AWS elasticbeanstalk` with `S3` service as backend server

Already use that `express.json({limit: '50mb'})` but still getting that error,
Here is my code:

app.js

```
const app = express()
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb', 
  extended: true, 
  parameterLimit: 50000
}));
```

AwsImageuploader.js

```
async function uploadFile(filename,filepath){
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: "bucker name",
        Body: fileStream,
        Key:filename
    }

    return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to increase the limit in your `.nginx` config on ElasticBeanstalk, e.g.:

```
server {
...
   client_max_body_size 50mb;
....
}
```

You can check [this article](https://medium.com/@robin.srimal/how-to-fix-a-413-request-entity-too-large-error-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-ac2bb15f244d), which explains in further detail.

Comment: From where i can find that .nginx config file on ElasticBeanstalk, Can you please help me, 

As you said that set `client_max_body_size: 50mb;` also many other answer said that same but nobody tell that from where we can find that file

Comment: Please read the article, it's explained really well. For example you can use ssh to access it on your ElasticBeanstalk.

Comment: Okay  thank you eol